# R: NaNs produced

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series in R Studio. Now I want to calculate the log() of this series. I tried the following:

```
i <- (x-y) 
ii <- log(i)
```

But then I get the following: `Warning message: In log(i): NaNs produced`
To inspect this I used: `table(is.nan(ii))` which gives me the following output:

```
FALSE  TRUE 
 2480     1
```

So I assume, that there is 1 NaN in my time series now. My question is: what code can I use, that R shows me for which observation a NaN was produced?
Here is a small data sample: `i <- c(9,8,4,5,7,1,6,-1,8,4)`
Btw how do I type mathematical formulas in stackoverflow, for example for log(x)? Many thanks

Comment: you can't take the log of negative numbers

Comment: `which` is probably the function you are looking for : `which(is.nan(log(i))) # 8`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in my comment, to know which observation generated the `NaN`, you can use function `which`:

```
i <- c(9,8,4,5,7,1,6,-1,8,4)
which(is.nan(log(i))) # 8
```

Comment: Note the `8` printed here tells you it's the 8th element of `i`, not that `log(8)` is `NaN`.

Comment: @Spacedman, yes, I'm well aware of that! ;-) I thought it was quite clear from my answer but do you think I need to make it even clearer ? Or maybe it's ok just with your comment in case someone may be mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

Use the test to subset your original vector with the values that produce NaN:

```
> i <- c(9,8,4,5,-7,1,6,-1,8,4,Inf,-Inf,NA)
> i[which(is.nan(log(i)))]
[1]   -7   -1 -Inf
Warning message:
In log(i) : NaNs produced
```

Here you see that -7, -1, and `-Inf` produced `NaN`.

Note that `log(NA)` is not `NaN`, its `NA`, which is a different sort of not-numberness.